# iOS adding a view of view controller but it's Not fully flushed to top

Tags: ios

[image]

I added a view of view controller by using

```
 [self.view addsubview view controller.view];
```

but as the picture indicates, it's fully flushed to the top.

the underneath view controller has a navigation bar.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in the first place. Either present this controller modally, add it as a child view controller of your current controller using the custom container controller api, or add a view (not a view controller's view) that you create in a xib file.

Comment: Don't you want to push the viewcontroller instead, so it can use the back button from the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to position the new view controller's view by specifying its frame. Otherwise it will do something you don't expect, like now.

Depending on what you want, it could be:

```
controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

This will just overlap the current VC's view with the new VC's view.

Or change it as necessary depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Like BlackRider said, a best approach is to assign the superview's bounds to the frame of the added view:

```
[self.view addSubview: viewcontroller.view];
viewcontroller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

This is the perfect way to set the size and position for a newly-added subview, to perfectly overlap a parent view.

Adding another UIViewController's view is most often not the best way.  However, I have found this technique may be the most effective way, if not the only way, to achieve some special animation transitions.  This, followed by removing the added view and presenting the new UIViewController with no animation.

If no special animation or view hierarchy arrangement is necessary, it's probably not a good idea.  If you want the new view controller to be full-screen, use:

```
[self presentViewController: viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

otherwise if you want it to be part of the navigation controller, push it onto the navigation controller's stack.  In your example, assuming **self** is the current top controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
```

For more info, check out Presenting a View Controller and Choosing a Transition Style:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW3